# How can drawRect request/rcv a image freshly computed by the model?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, ipad, drawrect

I have my first app running on iphone/ipad that uses Core Graphics and gesture recognizers (NOT OpenGL or touch events).  The App, view, and controller were set up using IB.  It's simply a View within a ViewController.  I added CG calls to draw into a CG Context.  The gestures are added to the view, but handled in the view controller. The view controller uses accessors to change variables that determine what is drawn in the view.  The computation (ie model) is embedded in the view.   The app works quite well, but I would like to add features, such as emailing and saving what has been drawn.  (I know I'll need other graphics contexts).

Conventional wisdom tells me I need to use MVC paradigm, meaning to factor the model out of the view into its own object.  So, I re-factored the code.  I manually added an NSObject for the model, which nicely contains the data and needed methods.  No compile errors or warnings.

Now, when the view's drawRect is triggered, I want to get an updated image from the model via the controller.  At the key place where I expect the image to be returned, NULL comes back.  I probably just don't have my object reference(s) correct, but I'm too confused to cut though the fog, and I'm working in a vaccum, so I am enlisting your help.  Thanks for reading.

SUMMARY and QUESTION

The View Controller always has the current parameters that it can pass to the model.
The model can compute a bitmapped image given those parameters.
I'm pretty sure I have that much down.

My question is (phrased various different ways):

What is the best way to get the image FROM the model TO the view (via the controller :^)
How should the View send a message to the view controller to initiate the request?

How can the model return the image to the controller?
I assume I'd just pass a CGContextRef back through whatever chain you recommend.

About me: I am new to OOP, Objective-C, Xcode, and IB.  I've watched most of the Stanford lectures several times, studied Goldstein's Dummies books, scoured Apple docs.   It is hard for a noob to glean appropriate level answers from these sources.  I just need more "experience". I'm so green, I'm not even sure how to refer to the view controller, other than to include "myViewController *viewController" in the view's interface definition!  I have been googling and reading the answers to similar questions here on Stackoverflow.   I can't beleeve I haven't found anything appropos.  I hoping for a practical principle or two to serve as my guide.

Please advise.

This is similar to reference-to-model-data-in-a-view-instance-drawrect, which was not answered satifactorily.

Comment: I read your question again a little more thoroughly, and you said " I assume I'd just pass a CGContextRef back through whatever chain you recommend." do not do this, pass a CGImageRef if you are sending an image. If you are sending point, use [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:] and store the values in an array to pass to the view. if you need several different functionalities like drawing both images and lists of points you should make a different UIView subclass for each and use your view controller to switch them out when appropriate.

Comment: The reason you shouldn't use CGContext ref to pass data is because it's a part of the view architecture, and this breaks the MVC pattern since the differnt parts of the program aren't separate. Essentially, the model, view, and controller should all be able to run separately. The only exception is that the view controller can know about both the model and view, but it still shouldn't be too tightly bound to either (ie. you should only need to make small changes, if any, to a part(class of group of related classes) to make it work in another app).

Comment: Good catch.  I wrote the wrong thing in my original statement.  I was trying to us CGImageRef in the MVC version of the program.  Maybe I'll edit that later. I understand the difference there.  That would really be warped to pass the CGContextRef from the view to the model (somehow) and ask the model to draw into that!  :^)  Sorry for the confusion.  I'll be back after working on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try if it suits you is to use NSNotifications.

The View gets the gesture information and sends high level events to the Controller (through direct messaging). The Controller takes those high level events and makes changes to the Model. The Model consumes those changes and then sends out NSNotifications to anyone concerned about the changes.

The View already knows about the Model, since that's how it gets its data to display, so the View will be able to subscribe to those changes readily. The Model doesn't really know about the View, so should have to send messages directly to it. However, something, somewhere, is interested in the Model changes, so it uses NSNotifications to broadcast and publish that information. This way, particularly with a complex model and/or simpler View, the Views subscribe only to what they are interested in. You can also easily have more than one View (or whatever) listening for NSNotifications at a time.

Another option is Key Value Coding/Observing, which iPhone supports, but it's not as ingrained as it is in Cocoa on the Mac. This handles much of Notification stuff semi-automatically for you, so you may want to consider that as well.

Comment: Thanks Will.  This helps complete my understand of how one make MVC work in practice.  On your answer, I'd like to clarify that in the working version of the app, the model math/logic is embedded in the view.  In my new "MVC" version, the model is separate, and the view and model are oblivious to one another.  It will be neat to have the working with them so loosely coupled.  I see that Rich also hinted about memory management.  I'll try things and see if I can check off an answer.  I am open to more advice!

Comment: The more generic the View, the less it "needs to know" about the Model. The game there is ensuring that the Model provides information that the View can actually use (i.e. if the View wants numbers, and the Model provides strings, you need some kind of intermediary). The Mac TableView is pretty generic but even it has a Table specific data source, but from there is can rely on KVO to bind columns and such. Personally, it is more important for the Model to be View agnostic, than the View to be Model agnostic. But there's always middle ground through Protocols to reduce coupling.

Comment: The thing that is (perhaps) unusual about my app is that the /gestures/ are what change the parameters of the model, not time or other inputs -- it's the user gesturing.  My gesture handlers modify parameters (kind of like sliders).  It's not as simple as the model spontaneously changing.  It's really /driven/ by the gestures.   Aside: I also want to be able to use the model for ordinary (non-gesture driven) purposes, that is to generate images based on stored sequences of parameters (think animation), or just by using a single set of parameters in another mode. See my other comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the view needs to get a new image when the image in the model changes. As Will said you can use notifications or key-value observing. Since your model shouldn't have to know about the view and the view shouldn't have a strong reference to the model. to do so add this to the viewDidLoad method in your view controller:

```
[model addObserver:self.view forKeyPath:@"<replace this with the name of the image property in the model>" options:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey context:NULL];
```

then in your uiview subclass make this method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"<replace this with the name of the image property in the model>"] {
         // set an image property that has been added to the uiview
         // the image property should be a weak reference ie. (nonatomic, assign)
         self.image = [change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
         [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

and finally in your drawRect: method you should draw the image.

Comment: Thanks Rich.  I was aware of these mechanisms, but didn't know if they were "robust" enough for my application, which I should have said was immersive and interactive.  Plus I was also at a loss to test!  I will certainly try this out and get back here later tonight US PST.

Comment: Hi. As in my original problem statement, it's the view that wants the model to give it a new image - based on the parameters as adjusted by certain gestures.  (It's like buttons or sliders in the view that user hits - a target action pattern - but not done via Interface Builder.)  Again, gestures affect parameters that currently live in the View Controller.  When a any of the gestures are handled, I set setNeedsDisplay. drawRect then needs to request a new drawing, as per params.  The view needs to get the image from the model via the view controller, I assume.  Would you still use KVO?

Comment: don't put your logic in the view. MVC works like this: you've got the model layer, the model-controller(data logic) layer, the application logic layer (controller), the view controller(view logic), and finally the view. try to imagine this as a box that has been divided into three parts (model, controller, view), and the parts that overlap can go together. For example, you can have a data class and a controller for it like fetched result controller. the fetched results controller provides the data logic to the view controller which will do it's own thing with it.

Comment: But what you should NOT have is the data controller (your model-controller) trying to obtain a reference to the view and send your data(the image) to it. Instead you should make IBActions in your view controller, and have them call methods in your data controller. Also use the fact that the view controller needs to know about both the view and the data-controller to your advantage. It should have some name for your model object so you can call [model addObserver:self.view forKeyPath:@"<replace this with the name of the image property in the model>" options:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey context:NULL];

Comment: If you do that your model will send a observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: to the view whenever the chosen property is modified. Finally your view shouldn't need to retrieve any data, you should set a pointer to the data and have drawRect: look in that pointer and based on what is stored it should draw something. Whether you're passing an image or a data structure containing points to draw or something totally different the drawRect method shouldn't try to find something to draw, it should be used for drawing the particular kind of data that your application uses.

Comment: To clarify another way, the view controller should be responsible for controlling what's in the view (view logic), so it should be telling your view what to draw not when to draw it. Thats why you should only setNeedsDisplay in the view itself (giving it the illusion of being smart), so that it only redraws when something external changes it's internal state (the current image to draw).

Comment: I think that using IBAction or IBOutlet will give me the linkage I need to communicate between view -- controller -- model.  I'll try that today.  I'm also commenting above.

Comment: To be clear, (and just a FYI at this moment) the setNeedsDisplay's are all being done in the View Controller, where the gesture handlers are.  The gesture recognizers are (added) in the view of course.  I have the handlers in the controller in both old and new versions.  Previously, when view & model were one,  I had ivars in the model+view being accessed via setter/getters - properties - from the view controller.  I've factored those ivars into the view controller, because I now want to be able to pass those values to the model object as needed (gesture) for it to recompute the image. -Later!

Answer (score 0):

HOW I SET UP LINKAGE BETWEEN VIEW | CONTROLLER | MODEL:

view|controller - From the view controller's loadView method I sent a message "hello:" to the view, containing a reference to 'self'.  In the hello method (of the view object), I stashed that pointer to the viewcontroller in a global variable for later use.

controller|model - I had the view controller alloc/init the instance of the model object and save the pointer to that in a global variable in the view controller.

I was able to use these two pointers as a bridge from the view to the model by going up and over through the vew controller.  I don't know what I am doing well enough to know whther I could have accomplished this linkage with IB or not.

RECAP OF HOW IT WORKS

drawRect sends a request/message for an updated image to the viewcontroller.

The view controller can act however it wants, but since it has the parameters as adjusted by the gesture handlers, it can pass a specific request to the model with those parameters.

The model then gets busy with CG, uses CGBitmapContextCreateImage (from the bitmap context in the model) and returns a CGImageRef (to the view controller). Then the view controller just returns the same CGImageRef as the result of the original request.  drawRect then does [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:modelImage] drawInRect:rect] to place the image in the view.

POSSIBLE DOWNSIDES, FINAL THOUGHTS

It /might/ slower but that may just be paranoia.  The model typically draws 8K lines or more to make the bitmap image, but the view doesn't have to do that much work to copy the resulting pixels. I should use Instruments to see what's up.

Also I'm concerned about image quality.  Seems OK.  I don't think I lose anything by first drawing into a CGbitmap context, then going through CGBitmapContextCreateImage, then finally the UIImage imageWithCGImage as above.  All same exact size.

Comment: OK, you are still doing this all wrong. What you need to do is to make a new class, call it MYDataController. Then add instance variables for any  If your app needs to be able to change the data that this contains add methods to the data controller and call them from your view controller. If you need to be able to modify the data based on user actions or gesture recognizers add methods to your view controller that will respond by calling the data controller. The data controller should be responsible for switching out data not modifying it.

Comment: if you need to modify the data add methods to the data object that will allow you to modify it. Next, do NOT request data in the drawRect: method, instead make an instance variable (weak reference) to a data object. Register the view or view controller to observe the active model object stored in the data controller. when the model sends change notifications set the view's pointer to the new value, and then setNeedsDisplay. The view shouldn't be asking what to display, using the observer pattern will give it the illusion that it is smart, making it easier to use.

Comment: By creating the image once the view is already about to draw you are slowing down your app considerably. Think about the flow for a moment, your view controller has some parameters that it needs to check, then it passes the params to the model which starts allocing a new image. Then once this is done, you pass the image ref back to the view (which should incur at least 2 msg_send's), then it allocs a uiimage and makes that draw. This will definitely take a while, to speed it up see my new answer.

Comment: Your new answer did speed it up (subjectively, but noticeably).  I'll need some time to consider your recommendation on MVC, which as you say is what this is all about.  I appreciate the thought and time you are putting into this.  I hadn't thought of introducing a vice-president sort of data controller.  I'll look at the overall design to see how such an object would relate to others I have designed but not coded. (PS. This isn't like uzumotion, et.al. - I'm not tracking speed or location of touch.  Instead, touches change discrete parameters, including one float.)  Thanks from PST zone.

Comment: To clarify, the model is a mathematical model, not a data model.  There is no data.  The graphic pattern is computed from scratch given the parameters. So in this sense there is no "data" that is changing, only the parameters.  The program has no built-in data (basically) nor does it get any data over the network, etc. FYI.

Comment: Note: My original Question was a bit misleading.  I should have spent more time formulating it.  The model doesn't just gurgle up an image on its own.  By "Fresh" I was referring to the "real time" interactive nature of the immersive experience.  Sorry again for any confusion.  In spite of that, the answers have been helpful.  I am still processing.  Thanks to both Rich and Will.

Comment: I spent about six months trying to learn to do MVC right, and I can see your having some trouble so  I'm happy to get you going in the right direction. I didn't understand that you meant a mathematical model, I thought that you had stored a cgimageref or bitmapcontext and possibly some other values in an nsobject and were treating it as data, but at the same time trying to control the data from the object. If you have a mathematical model then you already sorta have the data controller. The problem is that the data controller might be storing the data.

Comment: the design I've been trying to tell you about would have a data object the has an image and whatever other values the view will need for drawing. then you would make a data controller that you use to access the data. What you are trying to do is a little different and is a little harder to fit into MVC, but, I think that if you have a mathematical model it is a controller type thing. The model may or may not need to manage data (if you only need one to exist at a time it doesn't, but if you need to be able to switch them out consider that to be a state change in the mathematical model).

Comment: the model should also be responsible for notifying the view (or view controller) of changes it has made (even if you are just creating a new image, the view needs to get a pointer to the new image so it can draw it). I will continue to recommend that you use observers for this, but technically you don't have to if there's a faster way.

Comment: As to the parameters for the mathematical model. It's ok for the model or the view controller to store and provide access to these (as long as the mathematical model is handling logic), but you may eventually find that they go better with the data logic rather than the view logic (unless you need to access them from somewhere else too) since of course they are parameters to the data not the view (for clarity the data is a parameter to the view). But as I said it doesn't really matter right now.

Comment: btw, I'm in the PST zone too, I've just been getting up really f-ing early. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 0):

First off you will probably need to redraw whenever your parameters would cause a change in the data. So instead of requesting new data when the view needs to redraw, have the view or view controller monitor the data so that if it changes the view will redraw. drawRect REALLY shoudn't be requesting data, especially not indirectly from the view controller, this breaks the whole MVC design because the view needs to know about it's view controller (so it can request the data). Secondly for speed use the cgcontext to draw the image directly: `CGContextDrawImage(GContextRef c, CGRect rect, CGImageRef image);`.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks a load!  The CGContextDrawImages eems to have gotten the performance back where it was.  I tried this first since it was a simple change.  Now to consider your other advice on a data controller.